# Regex works on regex tester but doesnt work in php

Tags: php, regex

So i'm trying to get some information on real estates website titles.

they look like that

```
- Appartement  2 pièces 42 m² à louer Saint Ouen 93400, 765 € - Logic-immo.com
- Location appartement 2  pièces 47  m² Clichy (92) - 870  € - A Vendre A Louer
- Location appartement 3  pièces 67  m² Saint Ouen (93) - 1 065  € - A Vendre A Louer
```

i try to retrieve: **The price of the rent**

for this i use the following regex :

```
([0-9]?\s*[0-9]+\s*€)
```

which you can see work on the tester : https://regex101.com/r/RRYnMX/1 (i tried other testers)

which in my php looks like this :

```
    desc = $result['a_description'];
    $re = '/([0-9]?\s*[0-9]+\s*€)/';
    preg_match_all($re,$desc, $prix, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
    print_r($prix);
```

the results are good but not in the last case of the 3 examples where it only returns :

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 065  €
            [1] => 065  €
        )
```

I tried a lot of different possibilities but none seems to work.

EDIT

It works for the 2 first examples :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  740 €
            [1] =>  740 €
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  870  €
            [1] =>  870  €
        )

)
```

**EDIT 2 :**

```
$re = '/([0-9]?\s*[0-9]+)\s*€/u';
```

**stop working completely**

I tried

```
$re = '/([0-9]?\s*[0-9]+)\s*\x80/';
```

**stop working completely**

I tried

```
$re = '/([0-9]?\s+[0-9]+)\s*€/';
```

( i changed \s* with \s+)
**stop working completely**

I tried : https://regex101.com/r/RRYnMX/3

Works for all on tester, but not for 1064 on php. Here is the link : http://aeronet.be/appart/update.php

here is the output in text :

```
string(82) " Appartement  2 pièces 42 m² à louer Saint Ouen 93400, 765 € - Logic-immo.com"

 765

string(89) "Location appartement 2  pièces 47  m² Clichy (92) - 870  € - A Vendre A Louer"

 870

string(82) " Appartement  2 pièces 41 m² à louer Saint Ouen 93400, 910 € - Logic-immo.com"

 910

string(82) " Appartement  3 pièces 46 m² à louer Saint Ouen 93400, 850 € - Logic-immo.com"

 850

string(100) "Location appartement 3  pièces 67  m² Saint Ouen (93) - 1 065  € - A Vendre A Louer"

065

string(89) "Location appartement 2  pièces 48  m² Clichy (92) - 980  € - A Vendre A Louer"

 980

string(93) "Location appartement 3  pièces 52  m² Saint Ouen (93) - 980  € - A Vendre A Louer"

 980
```

Comment: Use `\x80` instead of `€`...

Comment: Depending on encoding, you may need to use `\x80` as Cylian indicates, or add the `u` modifier to enable Unicode matching.

Comment: I put an edit, the regex works fine when it's only 3 digit price. I tried \x80 and € with \u both made my regex stop working completely

Comment: Well, [it works even without `u`](https://ideone.com/7JrCx5), although you really need `u` when you use a regex with Unicode strings in PHP. Probably, the euro sign is not a literal one, but an entity. It is difficult to say since I could not repro.

Comment: That's the crazy thing is does also work with me when i try it like that. Here is a screen of my results http://prntscr.com/gl2tn0

Comment: The problem is that the `\s*` can be interpreted as no space between any of the numbers. With `\s+` you will get the correct result but with a space before the numbers that are less than 1000 so you'd have to add logic to remote that.

Comment: Please do a `var_dump($result['a_description']);` and provide us with the output.

Comment: Here is the output http://prntscr.com/gl31jn

Comment: Complete output in text version please!

Comment: I put it on the original post !

Comment: `var_dump("Location appartement 3  pièces 67  m² Saint Ouen (93) - 1 065  € - A Vendre A Louer");` shows 87 characters in length not 100. For sure invisible characters lie there.

Comment: You'r right, it was invisible characters thanks =)